# How to invoke a specific shell with python?

Tags: python, r, postgresql, shell

I want to invoke a specific command shell in python to execute some scripts. For exemple, in R, I use:

`system2(os_shell = "C:/Program Files (x86)/pgAdmin III/1.18/pg_dump.exe", args = "very long argument")`

Thanks to this code, I can backup my Postgresql's tables with a for loop.

Problem: I didn't find an equivalent in Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a program or call a system command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Postgres. Postgres will not be involved until *after* your shell script makes a connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to execute a application with args in a shell you can do that very easily with os.system

```py
import os
os.system("'C:/Program Files (x86)/pgAdmin III/1.18/pg_dump.exe' very long argument")
```

Tho I would recommend subprocess.call or subprocess.run

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["'C:/Program Files (x86)/pgAdmin III/1.18/pg_dump.exe'", "argument1", "argument2"]) #and you can add as many arguments you want
```